# bootstrap issue, "fileupload" not working inside of a modal

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-bootstrap

So, i am using a bootstrap modal, and inside of the modal, i want to use image upload, but when an image is selected, nothing happens, i am asuming it is a javascript issue, the script and the css is included outside of the modal in the header.

http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload

Any suggestions? I asume it is a javascript issue

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['login']) and !empty($_SESSION['login']) and $_SESSION['rank'] == 3) {


echo '
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="insert_post_modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
       <h3 id="myModalLabel">Insert Post</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <p>

    <form action="insert_post_sql" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <table border="0">


<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
    <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&text=no+image" />
    </div>
<div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;">
    </div>
<div>
    <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span>
        <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" /></span>
        <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
</div>
</div>
          </table>
     </form>

     </p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
     <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
     <input type="submit" button class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit Post">
     </div>
   </div>
   </form>
   ';
}
?>
```

Comment: Ignore the fact that the table does not have <td> or <tr> set, they are included, i just didnt post them, irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use **Document Ready function** because the Script is loaded prior to the Modal HTML

```
 $('document').ready(function(){
        $('#insert_post_modal').on('shown', function(){

           $('.fileupload').fileupload();

        }); 

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the fileupload on modal [shown](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) (i.e. when the user opens it):

```
$('#insert_post_modal').on('shown', function(){

   $('.fileupload').fileupload();

});
```

Can't test it right now though, I'm sorry

Comment: Does not work, it seems like the image is selected, since it defaults to the text of the img if clicked again, it is just not displayed in the "preview"

Comment: Did you read this? `Notice! Image preview only works in IE10+, FF3.6+, Chrome6.0+ and Opera11.1+. In older browsers and Safari, the filename is shown instead.` Do you get any error in the js console?

Comment: Yep 2 errors:

TypeError: $ is undefined
[Break ved denne fejl]  

$.fn.fileupload = function (options) {

bootst...load.js (linje 142)

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[Break ved denne fejl]  

$("#insert_post_modal").on("show", function(){

Comment: and i am testing in firefox, newest version, i did read it :)

Comment: Are you sure you included jQuery _before_  (IIRC TB puts all the js at the end of the document, if you loaded the extra plugin in another position it might be just the case) and not after the fileupload plugin?

Comment: Hey, just a last note, when it says
Name  type  description
uploadtype  string  Choose 'file' or 'image'. If omitted, the type is automatically determined based on the presence of a .thumbnail element.
name  string  Use this option instead of setting the name attribute on the <input> element to prevent it from being part of the post data when not changed.

do i need to pass the name in the function ? or ?

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){
$image_crop = $('#image_demo').croppie({
enableExif: true,
viewport: {
width:300,
height:300,
type:'square' //circle
},
boundary:{
width:400,
height:400
}
});

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.